# match the data with server to database in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have server and there i have store the some data for eg;username is abc and password is 123
and same password and come in json  i have to store same data in loca database by using sqlite in iphone 
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can store in sqllite3 database, Follow the below link..

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iPhone_Application

Comment: There are more                      http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/                                       http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/10/sqlite-tutorial-selecting-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you talk to your database, something like [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) might be a useful, open source starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SBJSON Parser and then simply call `[YourResponseString JSONValue]`. And you can return this into an NSDictionary.

Hope this helps.